# Joomla subtemplates: Create color variations

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I have created a template for Joomla 2.5, now I would like to create several variations of the same template which have different colors. I would like to select in the template settings which color the template should use.

How can I do that?

Comment: So you want to be able to choose the colour from the template settings?

Comment: Exactly, I want to have a drop down where I can select for example between the base style which is for example blue and a subtemplate with could be red or green.

Comment: Have you looked at the Joomla documentation for adding parameters to extensions?

Comment: No, do you have a link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add parameters in your template, you firstly need to add the following code to your *templateDetails.xml* file:

```
<config>
    <fields name="params">
        <fieldset name="advanced">

            <field name="template_colour" type="list" default="default" label="Colour" description="">
                <option value="black">Black</option>
                <option value="red">Red</option>
                <option value="green">Green</option>
            </field>

        </fieldset>
    </fields>
</config>
```

Once done, upload your CSS files to the template folder and give them specific names which are the same as your option values, such as `green.css`, `red.css` and `black.css`.

Then, open you *index.php* file and search for the code that is beimg used to import the CSS file. You can then add in the following code:

```
<?php
  $colour = $this->params->get('template_colour', 'black') // black is the default
  $doc = JFactory::getDocument();
  $doc->addStyleSheet(JUri::root () . 'templates/' . $this->template . '/css/'. $colour.'.css');
?>
```

What this does it, is get the colour value and applies it which then imports that specific colour css file

Hope this helps

Comment: @lanoxx - Glad it helped. I've added your fix to the answer for future reference ;)